# Create calculated column to add + work days to a date

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I am trying to create a calculated column to add + X work days to a date based on a work day steering table.

In the work day steering table, the bank days are flagged as 0.

What DAX formula should I use to create the calculated column and shift the date + work days further?

Expected Result:
[image: Expected Result]

Work day steering table:
[image: Work day steering table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either a **Measure** or **Calculated Column** code as given below-

**Measure Code**

```
add_day_dinamically = 
MAXX(
    TOPN(
        MIN(your_table_name[transport_lead_time]),
        FILTER(
            all(work_day_steering_table),
            work_day_steering_table[flag] = 1
            && work_day_steering_table[date].[Date] > MIN(your_table_name[date_column_name])
        ),
        work_day_steering_table[date].[Date],
        ASC
    ),
    work_day_steering_table[date].[Date]
)
```

**Calculated Column Code**

```
add_day_dinamically_column = 
MAXX(
    TOPN(
        your_table_name[transport_lead_time],
        FILTER(
            all(work_day_steering_table),
            work_day_steering_table[flag] = 1
            && work_day_steering_table[date].[Date] > your_table_name[date_column_name].[Date]
        ),
        work_day_steering_table[date].[Date],
        ASC
    ),
    work_day_steering_table[date].[Date]
)
```

Here is the output-

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mres, nice to see it worked. You can also put an up vote if it really helped :)

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani - Does the same approach work to calculate the number of work days between between two dates based on the steering table?

Comment: Thats bit diffrent, you can post a new question and hopefully someone will help :)

Comment: tks. challenge has been posted "Difference in work days between two dates"